# Change the cursor to a circle?

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, cursor

I'm building a website, and for part of it I have a whiteboard feature (which is basically a canvas). I'm trying to implement an eraser function for the whiteboard, and I wanted the cursor to change shape when the eraser is selected so that it matches the way in which the erasing is going to happen (at this point I'm trying to erase in a circle shape). So far I've tried this:

```
$('#canvasDiv').css('cursor','url(https://example.com/eraser_cursor.png)');
```

This however does not work for 2 reasons:

1. Although the image of the cursor is a circle it is not centered on the cursor so it would seem like the user is erasing something else.
2. Once the user starts erasing and he holds the "click" the cursor changes to a different shape.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: In your CSS declarations you should be able to utilize the `:active` pseudo selector to change the cursor when the user has clicked the mouse button. This is untested but may help... Also you should be able to either update your eraser icon to include some white space (a transparent section) that offsets the actual icon into the correct position, otherwise take a look at Pawel_W's answer.

Comment: the canvas tag is reserved to the <canvas> html5 element. If you wish to use the html5 canvas I can help but I doubt this is what you want to do. I suggest you to remove that tag since it is not related with the technology you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. there is also "x y" option - `cursor: url() x y` (as far as I know works only in FF/Chrome)
2. I think that `!important` should fix it

Comment: 1. it works  
2. I tried the !important option, but it doesn't seem to work (I use chrome). I had to load an event listener to mousedown and do event.preventDefault();